# Why does `python3 -m pip install .` not install my package, but `pip3 install .` does?

Tags: python, pip

I noticed (after a lot of digging) that `python3 -m pip install .` does not install my package located in the current working directory, since `.` is on `sys.path`; i.e. in this case, pip seems to think that the package is already installed. However, when doing `pip3 install .`, the package in current working directory is in fact installed as I expected.

I'd expect `python3 -m pip` to behave the same as `pip` (`PATH` issues aside!), but clearly they don't in this particular case. Why?

For the record, I'm running this in a docker container with an ubuntu bionic base image and `python3` installed from `apt install`.

Comment: `python -m pip install .` works for me perfectly — it installs a local project the same way as `pip install .` Can you show a project that couldn't be installed with `python -m pip install .`?